# Filter Rider Explorer Solution View

Tags: jetbrains-ide, rider

Does anyone know if Rider support filtering in its Explorer view?

I typically want my solution to include all projects, so when I search/build, I got everything. But in the meantime, the whole explorer tree is so overwhelming. I may focus on different subset of the solution in different time, hence I want to filter on a particular projects/folders that I am interested in.

I know in VSCode we could do filtering to show/hide certain items using settings in `files.exclude`. Does Rider have a way to achieve something similar?

Answer (score 2):

Feel free to upvote this feature request:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-16273/Scopes-not-available-on-solution-explorer

Right now (2022 year) it is only possible to search in the explorer tree